# Axon framework and Page response type

Tags: spring-data-jpa, axon

Is it possible to return a Page instead of a List from QueryGateway method? ResponseTypes.multipleInstancesOf allows to return only list instead of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this ResponseType isn’t available out of the box. However, you can create a class that implements the ResponseType interface. Both sending side and handling side will need to have this class.

There is an outstanding issue for out-of-the-box support on Axon Framework GitHub page.
You can find the issue I am talking about [here](https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/486).

For future readers of this questions, I am currently speaking of Axon Framework 4.3.3. Pretty confident 4.4 will not include it either, but after that, who knows...